# Electric potential and force in terms of Rydberg

Tags: potential, coulombs-law, dipole

Given charges +Q and +q, separated a distance r[nm], find the electric potential and repulsive force.

I am given a solution to a problem that is evaluated in terms of the Rydberg energy, but I don't follow it.
$$
U = \frac{Qq}{r} = 1Ry \times2a_0 \times\frac{Qq}{r} = 1.44eV \times \frac{Qq}{r}
$$
and
$$
F = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial r} = \frac{Qq}{r^2} = 0.231 \times \frac{Qq}{r^2}.
$$

Can some explain:

1. How to get the prefactors?
2. Why we can/would do this conversion?

Comment: Doesn't $a_0$ have units of Length while Ry has units of $\text{Length}^{-1}$? Something doesn't make sense in this analysis here unless the $2$ has dimensions not mentioned here.

Comment: No, we are using the Rydberg unit of energy.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your original formula more (what unit system since the $K_e$ is missing from coulombs law here, so I assume CGS units or related).